# Flutter: StreamBuilder into ListView doubling list items when adding to it

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

So I have a `StreamBuilder` which runs a query to Cloud Firestore for a list of documents. I then make each document into an item in my `ListView` and that works fine.

I am trying to edit the code because I want to add a search filter. I don't want to re-call data from Cloud Firestore each time a user is filtering the list.

So I decided to load all the data from Cloud Firestore into a list then use that list to build the `ListView`:

```
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      //widget build for complated call
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.data!.docs.length; i++) {
          DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
          GearItem tempItem = GearItem(
            doc['itemName'],
            doc['itemTemperatureRating'],
            doc['itemType'],
            doc['itemVolume'],
            doc['itemWeight'],
            doc['itemWeightFormat'],
            doc['manufacturer'],
            doc['packCategory'],
            doc.reference.id,
            doc['itemTempFormat'],
            doc['itemVolumeFormat'],
            doc['link'],
          );
          _listViewItems.add(tempItem);
        }

        //todo: cange ListView Builder to use new list
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _listViewItems.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
```

This works initially. While the stream is open if I add an item to the list then I get the list loaded twice on itself and double all the items.

I cant figure out why the items get re-added to the `_listViewItems` list when the stream auto updates.

Updated:

Stream section of `StreamBuilder`:

```
stream: db
    .collection('GearLockerItems')
    .where('userId', isEqualTo: userID)
    .orderBy('itemName')
    .snapshots(),
```

Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show the "stream:" parameter of your StreamBuilder.  I bet you have made a common mistake. Edit: Also, you realize any update to any of your items in the list will cause an entire new doc collection to be received?  And since you never clear out _listViewItems, it'll just keep getting longer and longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time there's a change to the data in Firestore, the stream fires an event with a `QuerySnapshot` that contains all data for that query/collection in the database.

The best option is to process `snapshot.data!.docChanges`, which allows you to see what changed between this `QuerySnapshot` and the previous one.

A much simpler fix is to keep processing the `snapshot.data!.docs` as you already, but clear `_listViewItems` before you process the new snapshot:

```
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
  // clear previous results
  _listViewItems.clear(); // 

  //widget build for complated call
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.data!.docs.length; i++) {
      ...

      _listViewItems.add(tempItem);
    }
    ...
```